# How to build ncurses statically

Tags: ncurses

Since Arch Linux does not provide any static libraries for ncurses, I need to make it myself. However, I don't see any option in the `configure` script that says anything about static linking. How do I make a static ncurses library?

Answer (score 3):

It's in `configure` but it's well-hidden:

```
Options to Specify the Libraries Built/Used:
  --disable-libtool-version  enable to use libtool's incompatible naming scheme
  --with-libtool          generate libraries with libtool
  --with-shared           generate shared-libraries
  --with-normal           generate normal-libraries (default)
  --with-debug            generate debug-libraries (default)
```

I suppose ncurses is old enough that static libraries are "normal" and shared libraries are the new hotness! Anyhow, if you build with defaults, or explicitly specify `--with-normal`, you should get static libraries (`libncurses.a`, `libpath.a`, etc.).

Comment: sure: "normal" libraries use default options, e.g., no debugging, no dynamic linking.  Anyone building from source sould have read [INSTALL](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/INSTALL#L1037), which spells that out.